# Design patterns package independence

Tags: java, design-patterns, dependencies, redundancy

My question is fairly simple, I haven't found a direct answer to it.
Is redundant code between two or more packages to achieve package independence considered as a good or bad practice, for instance I have two packages one does a download-and-cache , the other is for readfromserver-and-cache. while cached data and mechanism are completely different but have some common classes/methods.

Shall I create a third package which holds commons, and break package in-dependency?
Or shall I continue with two packages and will result in redundant code?
Lastly, to go deep in design and dependency, I'd appreciate it if you suggest me good material to read.

*Please note : I write in java , common code is not that much

Comment: It's hard to understand exactly what you're asking. Generally speaking, code that does the same job should be put into its own library and reused as much as possible. It's much better for package B and package C to depend on package A than for B and C to depend on each other. Best of all is if you can put interfaces in A so that you can change the actual classes without disturbing B and C.

Comment: Thanks for your response can you suggest me a good material to read?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you go for creating an interface for the Cache.  If the cache is not the same for both packages then common code can be in a abstract class and the individual packages can implement the rest.

Of course if the code is identical, then strip it out to its own jar.

Comment: Thanks for your response can you suggest me a good material to read?